# XSLT is not comparing multiple values in "when" condition?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Below is the part of the XSL where I am trying to check the file extension against multiple possible values  and the content type against  in the XML file where I already have preset value, but for some reason it is not checking the first condition. I have also put the xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:swa="http://ws.apache.org/axis2/mtomsample/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp dpconfig inc">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="manifest" select="dp:variable('var://context/INPUT/attachment-manifest')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ContType" select="$manifest/manifest/attachments/attachment/header[1]/./value/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ContentType" select="substring-before($ContType,';')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="$manifest/manifest/attachments/attachment/header[4]/./value/text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fileExtension" select="substring-before(substring-after($filename,'.'),'&quot;')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="File_CD" select="document('local:///FileIntake/Resources/FileServiceConfigData.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DocCategories" select="document('local:///FileIntake/Resources/DocTypes.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="IncomingFileSize" select="number(dp:variable('var://service/mpgw/request-size'))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="SetFileSize" select="number($File_CD/FileServiceConfig/FileSize)"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/IncomingFileSize'" value="$IncomingFileSize"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/SetFileSize'" value="$SetFileSize"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/ContentType'" value="$ContentType"/>
    <dp:set-variable name="'var://context/var/fileExtension'" value="$fileExtension"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$fileExtension != $DocCategories/DocTypeMapping/DocumentType/ContentValue/*">
            <dp:reject>Wrong FileType</dp:reject>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$ContentType != $DocCategories/DocTypeMapping/DocumentType/ContentType">
            <dp:reject>Unsupported ContenType</dp:reject>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$IncomingFileSize &gt; $SetFileSize">
            <dp:reject>File size exceeded enforced limit</dp:reject>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <dp:accept/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

DocTypes File:

```
<DocTypeMapping>
<DocumentType>
    <ContentType>application/octet-stream</ContentType>
    <ContentValue>xls</ContentValue>
    <ContentValue>xlsx</ContentValue>
    <ContentValue>dat</ContentValue>
</DocumentType>
</DocTypeMapping>
```

Can someone see if there is something wrong with the logic?

Comment: What would you like to do exactely? To check if the `$fileExtension` is found in any `ContentValue`?

Comment: @potame yes that is what I am looking to do.

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have posted the whole XSLT and there is no change in XML file.

Answer (score 0):

`A != B` tests if there is some value in B that is not equal to A. If B contains several values that are different the result will always be true. You almost certainly want `not(A = B)`, which tests if there is no value in B that is equal to A.

Also: you are testing `$fileExtension != $DocCategories/DocTypeMapping/DocumentType/ContentValue/*`. That looks at the child elements of ContentValue. But ContentValue does not have any child elements, so the RHS is an empty set, therefore it contains no value that is not equal to $fileExtension.